# Two limits and a discontinuity

Tags: limits, continuity

Suppose we have a function $F: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ with
$$
F(x) = \begin{cases}
\frac 1 2 x & \text{for } x < 1 \\
1 & \text{for } x \ge 1 \\
\end{cases}
$$
We have $\lim_{y \nearrow 1} F(y) = \frac 1 2$ and $\lim_{y \searrow 1} F(y) = 1$,
but what is the result of
$$
\lim_{x \nearrow 0} \lim_{y \nearrow (1 - x)} F(y) \qquad \text{?}
$$

Comment: Start by considering $\lim\limits_{y \nearrow (1 - x)} F(y)$, where $x < 0$. Or, equivalently, $\lim\limits_{y \nearrow z} F(y)$ for $z > 1$. What is this limit? It might, prima facie, depend on $z$. Or maybe it doesn't? Compute this first, then you can figure out the larger limit.

Comment: Same problem as $y \to 1$ since $x\gt 0$ and $x\lt 0$ give different limits.

Comment: @TheoBendit $\lim_{y \nearrow (1-x)} F(y)$ for $x < 0$ is always $1$, so the overall expression equals $1$, is this correct?

Comment: @user187803 Yes, correct.

Comment: @TheoBendit Thanks a lot